# How to make sure that change in props trigger a render only after a certain event is completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am playing a notification sound when the value of a state variable is changed. The Change of state variable is triggered by a change in props.
The Issue I am facing is that while a render is triggered due to change in state variable and notification sound is being played at the same time props again changes the value and so new render is triggered which causes the first notification sound to be stopped abruptly and new sound starts playing.

How can i make sure that new render is triggered only after previous render finishes playing sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take total control on your `render` using the `PureComponent` hook `ShoulComponentUpdate`. Here you can create your own logic to determine under what conditions your component should update (And re-render then). More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).